# End process but resume bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, signals, programming

I am trying to create a script in which part of it runs a command that can only be stopped by the user sending SIGINT to the process. I want the user to be able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to end that part of the script, but afterwards resume the rest of the bash script.

I have heard about the trap command, and I have tried using this with some janky implementation but I just don't know how it works. Can anyone help?

Comment: IIRC SIGINT goes to all processes attached to the controlling terminal of the script ( i.e. the whole process group ). If SIGINT is absolutely necessary, I'd recommend splitting the script into two parts - like server/client or producer/consumer type of thing. If not, I'd recommend sending SIGUSR1 instead : break script into functions and have a `trap` that handles SIGUSR1 when it is received via specific shell function

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried even failed attempt ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy You are mixing up process groups and session groups. You are right with it that SIGINT goes to the foreground process group of the terminal. But the entirety of the processes belonging to the same terminal is the session group.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Thank you for correcting ! Multiplicity of ways in which processes associate can be confusing sometimes.